# How to apply css on row headers in vaadin

Tags: java, css, vaadin7

I need your help in this problem . I have just started learning vaadin framework. I want to apply css on the row headers (First cell of each row) but does not got any success.Following is the code which i used.Kindly reply for any possible solutions, thanks ...!!!

scss code i am using for rowheaders:

```
.v-table-row-cell-content-rowheader {
        background: black !important;
    }
```

My code for Table definition:

```
Table customizedTable = new Table();
        customizedTable.addStyleName(Reindeer.TABLE_BORDERLESS);
        customizedTable.setStyleName("no-vertical-lines-or-border");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the **CellStyleGenerator** and apply it to specific cells in a row. 
More information about the CellStyleGenerator can be found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html#components.table.css)